# Training accuracy decreases as training set gets larger

Tags: classification, accuracy

I have a classification task to predict a binary outcome on a balanced data set, N=138. To make sure nothing fishy was going on in my feature set (overfitting, high correlation), I ran a PCA on the features I generated, and chose the first 2 PCA components for all the modeling/graphing below.

To make the graph:

Starting at training set size N=20, in increments of 2, I increase the size of the training set (where the test set is all remaining data) (both sets are always perfectly balanced). I train a Ridge Classifer on each training set, and record the accuracy of the classifer on the training set and on the test set for that particular train/test split.

To make sure I didn't pick some peculiar train/test split, I repeat this process 30 times, drawing a new train/test set each time. So for any particular point in the graph, the y-position of the line is mean train or test accuracy across 30 iterations.

To be clear, the left most x-position on the graph is when the training set size is 20, and the test set size is 138-20 = 118.
[image]

In normal circumstances, I would expect the training accuracy to increase as the training set size increases. And, as along as there is signal in the data, I would expect the test accuracy to rise as well.

So why would the accuracy as evaluated on the training set decrease as the training set gets larger?

I fear this might be happening because 1. there's no signal in my data or 2. my data is too small?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably seeing the training score decrease because the model becomes less overfit as you add more training data; with few training points, the model can fit to the noise more readily.  The test scores are increasing for roughly the same reason, but they also become more variable as the test size itself becomes smaller.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. So basically, even using just 2 PCAs, it's overfitting? Can I basically conclude that its almost all noise that is seperating the two classes?

Comment: @rdk There are degrees of overfitting; I'd say this isn't particularly extreme, but that's still the best culprit I can think of. Accuracy isn't a great metric, and to answer anything specific about it we'd need to know the class balance, but yeah those scores don't look promising. That said, the first two PCs are chosen as capturing the most spread in `X`, not necessarily anything useful about `y`, so including more features may well be more discriminative.